# formulario php error

Tags: php

Buenas gente. Al abrir mi pagina web se me envía el mail del formulario de contacto php vacio. Cuando en verdad lo que quiero es que al hacer click en enviar el formulario de contacto me llegue el mail con los datos ingresados.
les dejo mi html  y el php a ver si alguien puede ayudarme a encontrar el error.

```
html 

<form class="form-horizontal" action="../enviarcorreo.php" method="post">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-4" style="position:relative">
                                    <input type="text" name="Nombre" data-new-placeholder="Nombre" class="form-control label_better" placeholder="Nombre"required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <input type="text" name="Email" class="form-control label_better" placeholder="Email"required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <input type="text" name="Telefono" class="form-control label_better" placeholder="Telefono"required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <textarea class="form-control label_better" placeholder="Envianos tu consulta" rows="7"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group commands">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" >Enviar Consulta</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>

php 

<?php 
if(!isset($_POST['btn btn-primary'])) 
$nombre = $_POST['nombre']; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$telefono = $_POST['telefono']; 

$header = 'From: ' . $email . " \r\n"; 
$header .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . " \r\n"; 
$header .= "Mime-Version: 1.0 \r\n"; 
$header .= "Content-Type: text/plain"; 

$mensaje = "Este mensaje fue enviado por  " . $nombre . ", telefono: " . $telefono . " \r\n"; 
$mensaje .= "Su e-mail : " . $email . " \r\n"; 
$mensaje .= "Mensaje: " . $_POST['mensaje'] . " \r\n"; 
$mensaje .= "Fue enviado... " . date('d/m/Y', time()); 

$para = "stestebenlucas@gmail.com"; 
$asunto = 'ASUNTO DEL MENSAJE'; 


mail($para, $asunto, utf8_decode($mensaje), $header); 


?>
```

Comment: Agrega esto if(isset($_POST['btn btn-primary'],$_POST['nombre'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['telefono'])) asi aseguras que vengan todos llenos

Comment: Gracias alberto, pero aun agregando if(isset($_POST['btn btn-primary'],$_POST['nombre'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['telefono'])) al cargar la pagina web se envia un mail.
sigo con ese problema.

Answer (score 2):

Si:

```
<input type="text" name="Nombre" data-new-placeholder="Nombre" class="form-control label_better" placeholder="Nombre"required>
```

Entonces:

```
$nombre = $_POST['Nombre'];
```

Y no:

```
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
```

Las variables son sensibles a mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Answer (score 0):

Amiga y el name de

```
<textarea class="form-control label_better" placeholder="Envianos tu consulta" rows="7"></textarea>
```

se supone que lo recibes en `$_POST["mensaje"];`

Answer (score 0):

Los datos no te llegan porque el `name` de los inputs es diferentes, los recoges `$_POST['nombre']`, pero enviar `Nombre` tienen que ser iguales tanto en mayusculas como minusculas